# Control targetPort of generated service

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, quarkus

I want to use Google Cloud Endpoints with a Quarkus generated app, to do so I need a sidecar with the google endpoint container, like this:

```
 containers:
  - name: esp
    image: gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime:1
    args: [
      "--http_port=8081",
      "--backend=127.0.0.1:8080",
      "--service=my-service-endpoint",
      "--rollout_strategy=managed",
    ]
    ports:
      - containerPort: 8081
```

An Ingress resource (I created) points to a Service NodePort resource (Quarkus created) which points to a Deployment resource (I created) which contains this endpoints container and my web application container on port 8080.

Quarkus which is responsible to generate the Service NodePort always generates with a port and targetPort equals to the defined quarkus.http.port (default 8080) which is the web application port.
But I want the NodePort to target the endpoint sidecar port (8081 here) which will then redirect itself to 8080 once it has done all its endpoint work.

I tried lots of config and the last one was to add a sidecar one (instead of the Deployment config) which generates correctly this endpoint container info. But the Service NodePort does not point to it.

So my questions are:

- Is there a way to configure the generated Service NodePort targetPort property?
- Or is there a way to tell to quarkus to use the sidecar (or any other container name) as a reference for this targetPort?
- Or another way...